# Function Spaces: Characterizations of Positivity

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, spectral-theory, banach-algebras

**Context**

The problem here is about the characterization of positivity for real or complex valued functions:
$$\sigma(f)\geq 0\iff\sigma(f(x))\geq 0\text{ for all }x\in X\iff  f(x)\geq 0\text{ for all }x\in X$$

The point is that the first characterization reflects its intrinsic properties allowing to apply general results in the study of positive operators as integrals...

**Problem 0**

Let $A$ be an algebra with identity and $\Omega$ a plain space.
Consider the algebra of functions:
$$\mathcal{F}:=\{F:\Omega\to A\}$$
together with pointwise operations.

Is it true that the following characterizations of positivity are equivalent:
$$\sigma(F)\geq 0\iff\sigma(F(\omega))\geq 0\text{ for all }\omega\in\Omega$$
where $\sigma(F)$ is the spectrum of $F$ in $\mathcal{F}$ whereas $\sigma(F(\omega))$ the spectrum of $F(\omega)$ in $A$?

**Problem 1a**

Now, let $B$ be a Banach algebra with identity.
Consider the (Banach) algebra of bounded functions:
$$\mathcal{B}:=\{F:\Omega\to B:F\text{ bounded}\}$$
again with pointwise operations.
(Note that $F$ is not necessarily continuous.)

Is it still true that the characterizations of positivity are equivalent:
$$\sigma(F)\geq 0\iff\sigma(F(\omega))\geq 0\text{ for all }\omega\in\Omega$$
where $\sigma(F)$ again is the spectrum of $F$ in $\mathcal{B}$ whereas $\sigma(F(\omega))$ the spectrum of $F(\omega)$ in $B$?
(Here, a function is invertible iff it has a bounded inverse!)

**Problem 1b**

Next, let $X$ be also topological space.
Consider the algebra of continuous functions:
$$\mathcal{C}:=\{F:X\to B:F\text{ continuous}\}$$
again with pointwise operations.
(Note that $F$ is possibly unbounded.)

Is it still true that the characterizations of positivity are equivalent:
$$\sigma(F)\geq 0\iff\sigma(F(x))\geq 0\text{ for all }x\in X$$
where $\sigma(F)$ again is the spectrum of $F$ in $\mathcal{C}$ whereas $\sigma(F(x))$ the spectrum of $F(x)$ in $B$?
(Here, a function is invertible iff it has a continuous inverse!)

**Problem 2**

Finally, consider the (Banach) algebra of bounded continuous functions:
$$\mathcal{BC}:=\{F:X\to B:F\text{ bounded and continuous}\}$$
again with pointwise operations.

Is it still true that the characterizations of positivity are equivalent:
$$\sigma(F)\geq 0\iff\sigma(F(x))\geq 0\text{ for all }x\in X$$
where $\sigma(F)$ again is the spectrum of $F$ in $\mathcal{BC}$ whereas $\sigma(F(x))$ the spectrum of $F(x)$ in $B$?
(Here, a function is invertible iff it has a bounded and continuous inverse!)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Due to the pointwise structure it *formally* holds:
$$\sigma(F)=\bigcup_{x\in X}\sigma(F(x))$$

The difficulties arise as soon as additional requirements are tied upon the functions:

0) The formal inverse exists.
1a) The formal inverse is not necessarily bounded. (See below!)
1b) The formal inverse is continuous due to the Neumann series. (See [Contuity of inversion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/924341/banach-algebras-continuity-of-inversion/924360#924360)!)
2) The formal inverse is again continuous but not necessarily bounded.

Especially for complex valued functions it holds: $\sigma(f(x))=f(x)$

---

Consider the bounded function:
$$f:(0,1]\to\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto x$$
Then zero does not belong to its range but its formal inverse is unbounded:
$$f^{-1}:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: Just to be sure as someone downvoted: Does the argumentation miss a crucial point?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on this, so I might say stupid things, but lets have a go. Let me assume that $A$ is unital (with unit $\mathbb{1}$). The answer to your first question is positive, since $$\sigma(F)=\bigcup_{\omega\in\Omega} \sigma(F(\omega)).$$ Indeed, the inverse $h$ (if it exists) of the function $\lambda I-F$ satisfies $h(\lambda I-F)=(\lambda I-F)h\equiv 1$ pointwise and is therefore necessarily given by \begin{equation}
h(\omega):=(\lambda 1-F(\omega))^{-1}.
\end{equation} From this one sees that if $\lambda \in \sigma(F(\omega))$ for some $\omega$, then $\lambda \in \sigma(F)$ and conversely, if $\lambda \in \sigma(F)$ then for some $\omega$ the existence of $(\lambda 1-F(\omega))^{-1}$ must fail.

As for the continuous case, the collection of all continuous functions *do not* form a Banach algebra because you cannot define a norm there (unless your topological space is compact). You need to impose a boundedness condition: $$\|F\|:=\sup_{x\in X}\|F(x)\|_B<\infty.$$ This quantity defines a norm which makes your space a Banach algebra.

Now while an inverse $h$ of some $(\lambda I-F)$ must still satisfy the identity written above, the identity itself does not necessarily define a *continuous and bounded* function. An example illustrating this can be seen by taking $X=\mathbb R=B$ and considering the Banach algebra $C_b(\mathbb R)$ of bounded continuous functions.

Still, the case where $X$ is compact forms an exception for the following reason. The inclusion $$\bigcup_{x\in X} \sigma(F(x))\subset \sigma(F)$$ always holds. Suppose then that $\lambda\notin \bigcup_{x\in X} \sigma(F(x))$. Since $Im(\lambda I-F)$ is a compact subset of the open set $G$ of all invertible elements of $B$, and the inversion $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is continuous on $B$ it follows that the inverses of all the elements in $Im(\lambda I-F)$ also form a compact set (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_algebra) for all these properties), thus lying in some bounded ball of radius $a<\infty$. In other words, $$\|(\lambda I-F)^{-1}\|=\sup_{x\in X}\|(\lambda 1-F(x))^{-1}\|_B \le a,$$ thus giving a *bounded, continuous* inverse of $\lambda I-F$. This shows the opposite inclusion.

**EDIT**

Problem 0: As discussed above, the equivalence holds true in this case.

Problem 1a: In this case, for the same reasons as in the continuous and bounded case (see above) the equivalence is not true (even *with* compactness, since we do not have continuity).

Problem 1b: Here the equivalence is again true, since in the continuous & bounded case the only obstruction was boundedness.

Problem 2: In general no, in case $X$ is compact yes.

Comment: As the spectrum is a purely algebraic concept it does not require a Banach space structure but ok let's consider that case too (I will add it as further problem).

Comment: Ah I see, I accidentally used the word Banach algebra for the algebra of continuous functions - corrected and extended!