# Banach Algebras: Continuity of Inversion?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

*Context: This question is related to this thread: [Spaces of Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912191/space-of-functions-characterizations-of-positivity)*

---

Given a topological space $X$ and a Banach algebra with unit $B$.

Consider a continuous map $F:X\to B$ that is invertible pointwise:
$$F(x)F(x)^{-1}=1=F(x)^{-1}F(x)$$
Define its inverse:
$$F:X\to B:x\mapsto F(x)^{-1}$$
Then, is it continuous, too?
$$x_\lambda\to x\implies F^{-1}(x_\lambda)\to F^{-1}(x)$$

Put more abstract, is inversion continuous over Banach algebras with unit:
$$\iota:B^*\to B^*:a\mapsto a^{-1}$$

---

*Note: This is not the same as the formal inverse of operators:*
$$T:E\to E:\quad T\text{ continuous}\implies T^{-1}\text{ continuous}$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, because if $x$ is invertible and $\|y - x \| \le \|x^{-1}\|^{-1}$,
$$ y  = x (1 - x^{-1} (x-y)) $$
and $1 - x^{-1} (x - y)$ is invertible with
$$ (1 - x^{-1}(x-y))^{-1} = \sum_{j=0}^\infty (x^{-1} (x-y))^j$$ 
Moreover 
$$ \|y^{-1} - x^{-1}\| \le \sum_{j=1}^\infty \|x^{-1}\|^{j+1} \|x - y\|^j
= \dfrac{\|x^{-1}\|^2 \|x - y\|}{1- \|x-y\| \|x^{-1}\|}$$

Comment: Isn't it true that $||x^{-1}||^{-1}=||x||$?

Comment: No, it isn't.  Try almost any example in more than $1$ dimension.